# Add ken burn effect on video from list of images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ffmpeg, imagemagick, zooming

I have created video from list of images using ffmpeg

```
system("ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 out.mp4")
```

Now i want to add Ken burn effect, can i do it with ffmpeg or imagemagic or any command line tool on linux.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? will you write something to do this automatically (more then once)? Please check our list of [topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes, video will be generated automatically with the kenburn effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak of [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), or [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) technologies. But if you would like to create a panning effect made popular by Ken Burn, you would extract regions of an image, and animate them together.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# A 16:10 ratio
WIDTH=64
HEIGHT=40

# Extract parts of an image with -extent operator
for index in $(seq 40)
do
  TOP=$(expr 120 + $index)
  LEFT=$(expr 150 + $index)
  FILENAME=$(printf  /tmp/wizard-%02d.jpg $index)
  convert wizard: -extent "${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}+${TOP}+${LEFT}" $FILENAME
done

# Replace this with your ffmpeg script
SLICES=$(ls /tmp/wizard-*.jpg)
RSLCES=$(ls /tmp/wizard-*.jpg | sort -rn)
convert $SLICES $RSLCES -set delay 15 -layers Optimize /tmp/movie.gif
```

[image: Ken Burn effect]

Edited by Mark Setchell beyond this point... (just trying to help out)

Much as I hate editing other people's posts, the first part of Eric's code can equally be written this way if you find that easier to understand:

```
# Extract parts of an image with -extent operator
for index in {1..40}
do
  ((TOP=120 + $index))
  ((LEFT=150 + $index))
  FILENAME=$(printf  /tmp/wizard-%02d.jpg $index)
  convert wizard: -extent "${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}+${TOP}+${LEFT}" $FILENAME
done
```

Comment: `seq` is a utility the generates a sequence of numbers. Use `man seq` to view the manual. The `expr` simply evaluates an expression. Like before; simply execute `man expr` to view the manual. You can add debugging print & echo statements to understand the current values with each iteration.

Comment: One more question,  this program is for random sequence images and does not expect images to be in sequence?
and 

**convert $SLICES $RSLCES -set delay 15 -layers Optimize /tmp/movie.gif **

i have to remove the last convert command with my ffmpeg command right?

Comment: Thats correct. The `$RSLICES` is just the reverse of `$SLICES` for a demonstration in GIF. You would replace all of that with the `ffmpeg` command you are already using.